# Creating a database with a password , with phpmyadmin/mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

whenever I try to execute this sql command:

```
create database sitename
```

I get this:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'adwebhst'@'localhost' to database
>   'sitename'

I tried this:

```
grant all privileges on webcamporn.* to  'adwebhst'@'localhost' identified by '628ff50f63620c1b';
```

PHPmyadmin doesnt even have an option of creating a database..

How do I deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After GRAND ALL run this:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```